# I am trying to seed users and user roles in asp.net but only the roles succeed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hey This is probably a newbie question but I honestly can't find the problem after hours of searching for answers.

I am trying to create two roles and an admin user by seeding the database. I get no compilation errors but after running the application I couldn't login so I checked the database and noticed that the roles were created successfully but not the admin user.

Here is the class that I use for seeding:

```
 public class Initialize
 {
    public static async Task InitializeAsync(ApplicationDbContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService < RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        string[] rolenames = { "Admin","Member"};
        IdentityResult roleResult;

        foreach (var roleName in rolenames) {
            var roleExist = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
            if (!roleExist)
            {
                roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
            }
        }


        string username = "admin";
        string email = "admin@example.com";
        string password = "Secret123";
        string role = "Admin";

        if (await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(username) == null)
        {

            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = username,
                Email = email
            };

            IdentityResult result = await userManager
                .CreateAsync(user, password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My ConfigureServices :

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

And Here is my Program.cs :

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = BuildWebHost(args);
        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                Initialize.InitializeAsync(context, services).Wait();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "Error seeding");
            }
        }


        host.Run();
    }
```

Any help is appreciated  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try look at *userManager -> Store -> Users -> Results Views -> Message* after access via *serviceProvider.GetRequiredService*. You can have some error message about it here.

If it contains a message:

> "Cannot create a DbSet for 'ApplicationUser' because this type is not
>   included in the model for the context."

you must changed **ApplicationContext** class inherit from **IdentityDbContext** and it should be works fine.

Comment: Thank you for the answer have some stuff going on right now but I will try it as soon as possible.